# I've created a While loop to convert each char into it opposite form of Uppercase or Lowercase and i'm getting a bounds of array error at the end

Tags: c#

(not allowed to use LINQ or other libraries) I've created a While loop to convert each char into it opposite form of Uppercase or Lowercase and at the end of the loop I'm getting a 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'' and I've no idea how to resolve the error. The loop carries out as expected but faces this error when the last char in the array has been converted and retests the parameters  of the 1st embedded while loop. Also if there's an easier way to do this I'm all ears. Thanks in advance

```cs
string text2 = "HELLO my friEND";

char[] convert = text2.ToCharArray();
int b = 0;
int a = convert.Length;
while (b <= a)
{
    while (char.IsUpper(convert[b]))
    {
        char.ToLower(convert[b]);
        b++;
    }
    while (char.IsLower(convert[b]))
    {
        char.ToLower(convert[b]);
        b++;
    }
    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(convert[b]))
    {
        b++;
    }
}

string hello = new string(convert);

Console.Write(hello);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("test");
return 0;
```

Comment: In addition to mmathis' answer, remove the nested while loops.

Comment: @Llama is it bad coding practice or something?

Comment: In your case it's a significant cause of your problem, since the condition for looping is only applied to the main loop. It's also sort of pointless, as demonstrated by TheGeneral's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a lot of problems with your code, you weren't actually mutating the array by using the return result of the char methods, you had 2 `ToLowers()` and you were reading over the end of the array.

However, you can make it a little more succinct:

```
string text2 = "HELLO my friEND";

char[] convert = text2.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < convert.Length; i++)
   if (char.IsWhiteSpace(convert[i]))
      continue;
   else if (char.IsUpper(convert[i]))
      convert[i] = char.ToLower(convert[i]);
   else
      convert[i] = char.ToUpper(convert[i]);
```

Purely academic purposes, you could also use a `switch` here, though it's the wrong tool for the job:

```
for (int i = 0; i < convert.Length; i++)
   convert[i] = convert[i] switch
   {
      _ when char.IsWhiteSpace(convert[i]) => convert[i],
      _ when char.IsUpper(convert[i]) => char.ToLower(convert[i]),
      _ when char.IsLower(convert[i]) => char.ToUpper(convert[i]),
      _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   };
```

And as a bonus prize, here is a Linq variation:

```
string text2 = "HELLO my friEND";

static char Change(char c)
{
   if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) return c;
   return char.IsUpper(c) ? char.ToLower(c) : char.ToUpper(c);
}

Console.Write(string.Concat(text2.Select(Change)));
```

Comment: Big thanks, wish we could use linq as it takes away alot of the extra steps. but lecturer wants us to learn the fundamentals haha

Answer (score 2):

`while (b <= a)` needs to be `while (b < a)`. Indexes are zero-based, meaning the last index will be equal to `length - 1`.

You also increment `b` after every check (the `b++` in each of the internal `while` loops) - once the last letter is converted it checks the condition in the `while` loop again, and after it converted the "D" `b` is now 15 - but the string is only length 14. You need to check for this in each of the internal `while` loops, something like

`while (b < a && char.IsUpper(convert[b]))`

Alternatively, rework this method entirely to avoid these kinds of problems in the first place (by e.g., using a `for` loop).

Comment: just tried this, unfortunately didn't work. I've debugged and it looks like the error is thrown up when its retesting convert[15] which is D changed to d against the  `while (char.IsUpper(convert[b]))`  so hasn't reached the initial while condition yet

Comment: @CallumStanbury updated my answer to account for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please optimize your code like this：

```
        while (b < a)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(convert[b]))
            {
                convert[b] = char.ToLower(convert[b]);
            }
            else if (char.IsLower(convert[b]))
            {

                convert[b] = char.ToUpper(convert[b]);
            }
            b++;
        }
```

Comment: @CallumStanbury I made a mistake , and it fixed now.